# Cant fetch data. Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Im getting this error when I try to retrieve posts from a specific user. The code to fetch the data is correct. Not sure what the error is coming from.

From server side
[image]
Client Side

[image]

Below is the code for the individual post.

```
const UserPosts = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState()


    useEffect(() => {
        const id = localStorage.getItem("userId");
        const sendRequest = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get(`/post/user/${id}`)
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
            const data = await res.data;
            console.log(data)
            return data;

        }

        sendRequest()
            .then((data) => {
                setUser(data.user)
                console.log(data)
            })
    }, [])


    return (
        <div>
            {user &&
                user.posts.map((post, index) => (
                    <Post
                        id={post._id}
                        isUser={true}
                        key={index}
                        username={user.username}
                        caption={post.caption}
                        selectedFile={post.selectedFile}
                        createAt={post.createAt}
                    />
                )).reverse()}
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserPosts;
```

This is the post controller for that route

```
export const getUserById = async (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.params.id;

    let userPosts;
    try {
        userPosts = await User.findById(userId).populate("posts");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    if (!userPosts) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: "No Post Found" })
    }
    res.status(200).json({ user: userPosts })
}
```

Comment: You're attempting to send status 404 then right afterwards sending status 200.

Try adding a return statement right after your `res.status`

Comment: Im still getting the same error

Comment: That is okay express can give you a response with it.

Comment: But im not getting the data to render on the page though

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.

While my main issue was the component not rendering the data on the page due to fetching the wrong login route on the client side. When the user is logging in, I stored the user Id on local storage and retrieve the user Id from local storage to fetch for the user's id when rendering the user's post.

The issue on the server side was due to not returning on the if statement and led to returning 2 response.

Comment: Although that might be the cause of the 404, the cause of the problem as it's articulated in your question is that you can't send a 200 after having sent a 404 and as Gavin pointed out, you're missing a return statement.

Comment: I did added the return statement at the end, although without it, it still did render the data I wanted. The 404 is inside an if statement.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't want a return statement _at the end_.  You want the return **inside** the `if` statement to prevent **falling through** to the next `res.status`.  Like this: `if (!userPosts) { res.status(404).json({ message: "No Post Found" }); return; /*to prevent falling through to the next res.status*/  } /*then outside the if...*/ res.status(200).json({ user: userPosts })`

Comment: I agree with wyck. a return statement can usefull at that point

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
        const id = localStorage.getItem("userId");
        const sendRequest = async () => {
            const {data} = await axios.get(`http://localhost:backend-port/post/user/${id}`)

            setUser(data.user)
        }

        sendRequest()
    }, [])
```

Please try that out

Comment: I get this error Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on

Comment: can i see the full exception

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, as @Gavin points out, is that you respond with a status of 404, but then fall through, out of the `if` block, to another `res.status` call.  You can't send the status more than once like that, and you must restructure your logic to prevent prevent calling `res.status` twice.  Two easy viable solutions:

#### Option 1: Add a `return` in the error-handling block to prevent falling through to the non-error case.

```
    if (!userPosts) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: "No Post Found" })
        return;
    }
    res.status(200).json({ user: userPosts })
```

#### Option 2: Use an `else` block to separate error-case from non-error case in a symmetric way.

```
    if (!userPosts) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: "No Post Found" })
    } else {
        res.status(200).json({ user: userPosts })
    }
```